ModelEntity.loadAsync is deprecated in iOS 18
I am using the following code on iOS 18 and it gives me issues that ModelEntity.loadAsync is now deprecated. Any ideas how to fix this issue?
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import Combine

class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
    
    weak var view: ARView?
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
   
    @objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        guard let view = self.view else { return }
        let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: view)
        
        let results = view.raycast(from: tapLocation, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal)
        
        if let result = results.first {
            
            // create anchor entity
            let anchor = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: result)
            
            cancellable = ModelEntity.loadAsync(named: "shoe")
                .sink { loadCompletion in
                    if case let .failure(error) = loadCompletion {
                        print("Unable to load model \(error)")
                    }
                    
                    self.cancellable?.cancel()
                    
                } receiveValue: { entity in
                    
                    anchor.addChild(entity)
                }
             
            view.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        }
    }
}


Pity that loadAsync(named:in:) type method is deprecated. The evolution of a structured concurrency continues, and everything you need can be found in the RealityKit/SwiftUI API. The solution is obvious: create AR app based on both frameworks – SwiftUI and UIKit. If you want to asynchronously load an Entity from a bundle, use the following initializer:
@MainActor @preconcurrency 
convenience init(
    named name: String,
     in bundle: Bundle? = nil
) async throws


Here's the example.

Thanks Andy! If I just wanted to target SwiftUI would I be looking at RealityView and forget about Coordinators etc?

It depends. You can just load models the way I showed you and continue using ARView with all its stuff. Or forget ARView and use RealityView, but it’s still not as great as we’d like.
